# Is Jersey (REST Framework for Java) used widely in Production?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

We're looking at various frameworks to create a REST Service in Java. One obvious choice is Jersey.

However, we have not been able to find many testimonies that say Jersey is used by xyz number of users.

We're trying to see following -

1. How widely used is Jersey in 2017?
2. Is it actually used by companies for in-production services?
3. Are there any performance or stability concerns about it?

It would be appreciated if you can provide any links.

Comment: I've personally seen more CXF being used in the wild, but Jersey is not uncommon. Undertow and Camel are options as well.

Comment: @harshakumarReddy Please do not suggest that people cross-post questions on communities where they will not be accepted. Software Engineering has the same rules about recommendation questions as Stack Overflow - that is, they are not allowed. When people receive wrong advice such as this, they tend to have a poor experience after their cross-posted question is down voted, closed, and deleted in short order.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly legitimate question, the type that is frustrating when closed.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Jersey front-page](https://jersey.java.net/):

> Goals of Jersey project can be summarized in the following points:
>
> - Track the JAX-RS API and provide regular releases of production    quality Reference Implementations that ships with GlassFish;

Granted, this is not a statistical measure of production use, but Jersey is certainly viable for production use.

Jersey aside, if you make sure your implementation relies only on classes, annotations, and interfaces from the JAX-RS specification, it will be vendor agnostic. This should be your goal as you can then easily switch implementations in your production environment (no source code changes necessary).

Comment: That's reassuring. I don't think there are any alternatives if you want to use JAX-RS (even if you use Tomcat for the HTTP layer).